# ASP.NET Core 6 project auto logout after 10~20 minutes

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-6.0

I Just Want to Know Why I Get Banned for Asking Questions!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!???????????????????????????????????????????

This problem only exist in Online Host not Local Host.

I watched [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sogS0DtejVA) and do authentication and authorization of my project. On localhost, it's okay, but when I switch to online host that is Windows Host with Plesk (I think it is IIS but I'm not sure), user will get logged out after 10~20 minutes, no matter what I use - `IsPersistent` or not (keep user log in).

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication("MyAuth").AddCookie("MyAuth", options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyAuth";
    options.LoginPath = "/login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/logout";
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30);
});

List<Claim> claims = new()
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.ID.ToString()),
};

ClaimsIdentity identity = new(claims, "MyAuth");

ClaimsPrincipal principal = new(identity);

AuthenticationProperties properties = new() { IsPersistent = login.RememberMe };

await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyAuth", principal, properties);
```

I tried everything that is from [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sogS0DtejVA), but nothing works. And I don't know how to fix it. I searched a lot and most of tutorial is for ASP.NET Framework - not for ASP.NET Core.

What I tried:

> 1. add options.SlidingExpiration = true; to  AddAuthentication().AddCookie
> 2. add `builder.Services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o => o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(10));` to program.cs
> 3. ExpiresUtc to AuthenticationProperties.

Update: I find this but don't know what to do? i can't find those setting is Plesk.

> Mysterious Logout on IIS Server
>
> Despite all of these settings you may experience that users are loging
> out after some minutes eg 20mins. Most probably you will not catch
> this behaviour on local while developing your application. It is
> related with some settings on IIS.
>
> To fix this behaviour, first you need to go to advanced settings of
> application pool.  You will see a setting called “Idle Time-out
> (minutes)” and must set as 0. Its default value is 20mins. It means
> that if no new request comes for 20 mins, worker process will be shut
> down.
>
> When an app restarted or worker process restarted and If the keys
> related with authentication kept in memory;
>
> Cookie based authentication tokens will be invalid and users will need
> to log in again.
>
> So to keep keys persistent, we need to set one more setting on
> advanced settings of Application Pool; Load User Profile must be set
> to True. So keys will be stored in a folder on operation system.
> (%LOCALAPPDATA%/ASP.NET/DataProtection-Keys)

Comment: Please do not link to YT. Instead, provide details on how you do authentication, is it cookie or JWT, what's the configuration. Linking to YT could be a form of advertising (you or someone related to you could be the author of the YT material).

Comment: ok i will send it now.

Comment: and for youtube tutorial i don't know anything about it sorry for that

Comment: options.SlidingExpiration = true; in cookie options should solve your issue, regards.

Comment: You can set `IsPersistent=true` in `HttpContext.SignInAsync()` to make the expiration of cookie based on the time you set instead of session. refer to [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-7.0#persistent-cookies)

Comment: thanks but `options.SlidingExpiration = true;` not fix my problem.

Comment: `IsPersistent` is true when user check remember me. but no matter it's checkced or not. user will log out after 20 minutes.

Comment: Have you checked the expiration of the cookie in the browser

Comment: yes when i check RememberMe checkbox and then ckeck in browser it's 30 days ahead from now.

Comment: YouTube videos aren't tutorials or references. What do you mean `Online Host`? If you mean a web site hosted on a cheap plan, you should expect the server to shut down if it's not active after a while, losing all cached data. That include any session data.

Comment: HTTP is stateless. There are no user sessions in the protocol itself. ASP.NET Core keeps track of a *user* session that needs to be stored somewhere between HTTP calls. Session state can be stored in memory (for small sites) or a database for larger, multi-server sites. The session cookies stored in a browser are simply pointers to the session, not the session data itself. If your web app uses in-memory storage and gets recycled by the hoster after 10 minutes then yes, the session state is lost as well.

Comment: Check the ASP.NET Core docs on sessions and state management at [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0). The question contains no code that handles session state so it's hard to know how you've set up the application

Comment: As for `To fix this behaviour, first you need to go to advanced settings of application pool. You will see a setting called “Idle Time-out (minutes)” and must set as 0`. That's *not* how you handle *sessions* and definitely not something you can change on *any* hoster, unless you set up a VM from scratch. Even on an intranet, the web admins would have some very strong opinions if you asked them to keep your rarely used app alive "just because"

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos yes that is what i mean. so how to fix it? i can't change the host and server is always online but is Shared Hosting not VPS or Dedicated Hosting that i can do anything with it.
so how to fix it? is there anyway i can save those data in HDD not in Memory?

Comment: and one thing in every 10 minutes when i go to my website it's took 10~20 seconds to load the site but after first request it's load less than second. so after 10 minutes it's reset every thing that cached in Shared Host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Just add this line of code before `var app = builder.Build();`:

```
builder.Services.AddDataProtection().PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())).SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
```